# Speedup Sklearn model fitting

Tags: python, performance, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, thread-priority

I am profiling Sklearn model:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(..., n_jobs=-1)   
%time clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
...

CPU times: user 2min 35s, sys: 3.07 s, total: 2min 38s
Wall time: 8min 40s
```

Wall Time is significantly larger than CPU total time.

1. Does it mean, that Sklearn is not fully utilizing CPU resources? I
   haven't any programs on my PC started explicitly, except Jupyter
   Notebook.
2. How do I can increase CPU priority for all processes, that Sklearn
   have started?

OS: Kubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Much higher wall time than CPU time usually indicates an I/O bottleneck, but that should not happen training a scikit-learn model on data you have in memory. The next thing I would try is setting `n_jobs` to the number of physical CPU cores.

Comment: No, it didn't help.